# Angular Yeoman generator

Tags: angular, yeoman

When I run

```
yo angular [app-name]
```

It generates an AngularJS project. How to generate Angular 4 project with Yeoman generator?

Comment: You need to find a generator that *does* create the kind of project you want. Or just use the Angular CLI, which provides similar functionality.

Comment: @Aravind the OP wants an Angular, **not** AngularJS generator, which is why I removed that tag.